# Archive Thumbnail Gallery

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am trying to create a Archive page with a list of all my posts with thumbnail and a small excerpt underneath.

kind of like what this guys is doing

http://www.globinch.com/2010/11/01/how-to-create-wordpress-thumbnail-based-post-archives/comment-page-1/#comment-36825

I actually followed his method and found out after some screwing around that he is calling thumbs with custom field thumb value

I was hoping to pull the thumbs from my featured thumbnails images as I dont want to go into every post and add a thumbnail.

so basically
1. Create a thumbnail list like u see in that dudes link
2. Be able to size the thumnbnails

Any thoughts, take in mind I am not a programming genous:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code on the site you linked to with post thumbnails, if you change one line.

Instead of

```
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', true) ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
```

Use

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

See the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) for more information.

Comment: thanks I did find that as well and got it to work with some tweaking with image sizes and a regeneration thumb plugin as well.